# How to click on the checkbox using Selenium Javascript and Xpath?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am trying to target the checkbox to agree to the terms and conditions but have no name or id to use to target. I have `innerHTML` and `innerText` that I am trying to target with selenium but am only encountering errors. I am using Javascript and testing on chrome.

Code trial:

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*innerText[text()=’I am at least 18 years of age and agree to the Official Rules.’]")).click();
```

Error:

```
let err = new ctor(data.message)
              ^

InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //innerText[text()=’I am at least 18 years of age and agree to the Official 
Rules.’] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//innerText[text()=’I am at least 18 years of age and agree to the Official Rules.’]' is not a valid 
XPath expression.
```

Image of the checkbox:

[image: imageofcheckbox]

Properties of the checkbox:

[image: propertiesofcheckbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired tag is a `<label>` tag.

---

### Solution

To click on the [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) associated with the text *"I am at least 18 years of age and agree to the Official Rules"* you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='opt_rules']")).click();
```